# SQL Server datetime issue?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, t-sql

C# code is reading data from database through dynamic queries.

```
Select ID, TransDate from Table_01
```

Business logic is processing the data and finally putting back the date into the database again.

```
INSERT INTO Table_02
( ID,ClosingDate) VALUES
( 1,Convert(DateTime, '27/07/2011 12:00:00 AM',120))
```

Since date format, i am inserting, is dd/MM/yyyy. Sql Server does not like it and .net throwing this error:-

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in
>   an out-of-range datetime value

If i change it to MM/dd/yyyy or yyyyMMdd then it works.

But system regional date time settings can be changed any time by any user, so I am looking for some concrete solution.

What is the best way to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the dateformat and using Cast:

```
Set DateFormat DMY
GO
INSERT INTO Table_02( ID,ClosingDate) 
Select 1, Cast('27/07/2011 12:00:00 AM' As DateTime)
```

Comment: SQL Server does not like it either. Here is the error : The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Comment: @User13839404 - Really? I tried it on my local 2005 instance and it works.

Comment: Sql server is sitting on other machine where system datetime format is yyyy-MM-dd. Where app is running, datetime format is dd/MM/yyyy. I dont know if it matters?

Comment: @User13839404 - Nope. When you call `Set DateFormat`, you are forcing the interpretation of the dates regardless of the server's default or culture setting.

Comment: @User13839404 - Note however that I'm using Cast instead of Convert.

Comment: my bad. I didn't set the DateFormat DMY as you mentioned. It worked. But does this mean thats the format stays on that system forever unless changed manually?

Comment: @User13839404 - No. It only applies to that query or connection. You could change it each time if you wanted. In fact, many drivers will simply send `Set Dateformat` when they are sending dates.

Answer (score 2):

The converstion style 120 is: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)`. Try using 103 (`dd/mm/yyyy`) instead.

```
INSERT INTO Table_02
( ID,ClosingDate) VALUES
( 1,Convert(DateTime, '27/07/2011 12:00:00 AM',103))
```

You can find the documentation for the styles [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: Or change your insert value to YYYY-MM-DD, which is considered "canonical" across most systems and cultures.

Comment: @Joe, Hi, but problem is this date format can be anything depending upon the computer date time settings...

Answer (score 1):

IMO the best way would be to use parameterized query - then the driver / server takes care of converting data into correct format.

Comment: Right. I am changing it gradually. its big system. But now its a time constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Stick to `yyyyMMdd` it will always work regardless of regional settings and date format settings. Beware of `yyyy-MM-dd`, it will not work when date format is DMY. http://www.sommarskog.se/wishlist.html#YYYYMMDD